# Developing an offline dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, translation, nokia-s40

Please I'm Relatively new to Java Programming am a first year Computer Science Student please I want to develop an offline dictionary for Nokia s40 phones .jar that translates English to my Local language I've googled and searched the discussion topics for similar posts but I've not found any related posts please any Help and information will be useful cos am still a beginner Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Ani, I want to help you but the site rule states clearly that it won't accept "broad & ambiguous question". This question is going to be closed pretty soon, I guess. But why don't you try to come up with a few idea, then present them in the question and clearly state where you're stuck?

Answer (score 5):

If everything is new to you, I suggest to learn to write from basic first, i.e, learn to write a simple dictionary application for desktop. After that you will have an idea on what should be the program's structure and component. Then you can start learning how to program to Nokia phone and port the application over.

Start by looking at source code of some open source dictionary. For example, openDict
http://opendict.sourceforge.net/?cid=1

Comment: +1 for the pointer and open source reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. @HoàngLong please is there a way I can reach maybe by mail? am so happy you want to help.

Comment: @AniTochukwu: you can contact me through the site on my profile

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is nothing but  something like a map, that maps two strings together, or a keyword to a description. You can use the [MAP Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to begin with.

You can use the above to do something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> myDictionary = TreeMap<String, String>();
    dictionary.put("Hello", "Ola in Spanish");
    System.out.println(myDictionary.get("Hello"));
```

Here,

- key - provides access to a value.
- value - maps to a specified key.
- Hello - Ola in Spanish

Comment: Generics is not available on Nokia S40 (Java ME)